# Modify Reference on Taxonomy Field Output

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to modify the output of a 'Reference on Taxonomy Field'.
I created a 'Reference on Taxonomy Field' in a content type that relates to terms in a vocabulary that have a title and a picture.
The content type is displayed by a view that outputs the fields of the content type. I added the field and created the template file **views-view-field--kategorieseiten--page--field-produkteigenschaften.tpl.php** and it works.

It should be displayed like this:

```
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" target="_blank" data-original-title="TERM_TITLE">OUTPUT_OF_THE_TERM_PICTURE</a>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to address the fields from the taxonomy term, since they are not directly stored in the node.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to load the fields of the taxonomy term with this code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * This template is used to print a single field in a view.
 *
 * It is not actually used in default Views, as this is registered as a theme
 * function which has better performance. For single overrides, the template is
 * perfectly okay.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $view: The view object
 * - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
 * - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
 * - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
 *
 * When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
 * $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}
 *
 * The above will guarantee that you'll always get the correct data,
 * regardless of any changes in the aliasing that might happen if
 * the view is modified.
 */
?>

<?php $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load(54); ?>
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" target="_blank" data-original-title="<?php print $taxonomy_term->name; ?>"><img src="<?php print $taxonomy_term->field_icon['und'][0]['filename']; ?>"></a>
```

But I want to load the terms dynamically from the tid stored in this field:

[image]

The field 'field_produkteigenschaften' is part of the content type and is stored in the node object.

**How do I now address the tid stored in the field 'field_produkteigenschaften' in this template?**

Answer (score 0):

I could get the output with:

```
$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_produkteigenschaften['und'][0]['tid']
```

Complete code:

```
<?php if ($row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_produkteigenschaften) { ?>
<?php foreach ($row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_produkteigenschaften['und'] as &$eigenschaft) { ?>
<?php $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($eigenschaft['tid']); ?>
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" target="_blank" data-original-title="<?php print $taxonomy_term->name; ?>"><img src="<?php print image_style_url("icon", $taxonomy_term->field_icon['und'][0]['uri']); ?>"></a>&nbsp;
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { print "&nbsp;"; } ?>
```